# Display the contents of a database query with Node.js and Handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I am routing from one page to another, and am trying to display the contents of the database query on the next page in my user display.js

```
exports.list = (req, res) => {
console.log("we have activated userdisplay.js\n");
db.query('SELECT * FROM User', (error, results, fields) => 
{
    console.log('we did a query');
    if(error) 
    {
        console.log("Error: ",error);
        res.send({
            "code": 400,
            "failed": "Error occurred"
        });
    } else {
        console.log("Results: ",results);
        /*res.send({
            "code": 200,
            "success": "Database successfully logged"
        });*/
        res.render('tempdisplay.html', {data: results});           
    }
});
```

}

So I have the data, but now I need to display it. I tried using handlebars to convert the data object sent by res.render() in the tempdisplay.html file to strings using

```
<script>

  var user = [
      {{#each data}}
          {
              email: '{{email}}',
              fname: '{{fname}}',
              lname: '{{lname}}',
              pass: '{{pass}}'
          }
      {{/each}}
  ];

</script>
```

When I try to run this to convert them to strings it gives me a "Invalid regular expression: missing / in file" Error. This error only happens when this script is present. I have jquery and handlebars included in the file, and my other files work with the pathways/cdn. I don't really seem to understand how I would go about using handlebars to display the data. If I make another js file, I won't be able to see the data object returned to tempdisplay, but if I try to make a handlebars script in the html file it gives me syntax errors.

Comment: You're supposed to put handlebars braces directly in your HTML. Provided you've set handlebars as your view engine, express's `res.render` will load the template, then insert the data and send the result to the client (browser).

Comment: When I try to do {{data}} in the html file, I get the [object][Object] return for every user in the database. That is why I felt the need to make a script to stringify.the data.

Comment: The above template will work in theory, but the result won't be a valid array (no commas in between users). If you really need that data on the client-side, just use `res.sendJSON` and request it on the client using AJAX. However I'm still not sure what your actual goal is? How do you plan on using `var user` in the client?

Answer (score 3):

To display data on the client, the usual method is to insert it into a template on the server:

```
// fill tempdisplay.hbs with results, send to client
res.render('tempdisplay', {data: results});
```

An example of a template file `tempdisplay.hbs` is this:

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        {{#each data}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{this.fname}}</td>
                <td>{{this.lname}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What does `this` do?

Comment: @LV98 It refers to the current element of the `data` array.